# WebStorm's file watcher to compile SCSS with Dart

Tags: ruby, sass, dart, webstorm, file-watcher

I found out that Sass is moving from being compiled with Ruby to Dart, as their main page suggests - https://sass-lang.com/. I followed the steps there, got myself the Dart compiler and indeed I can run the command they suggest - `sass source/stylesheets/index.scss build/stylesheets/index.css` and successfully compile my SCSS to CSS.

The problem I'm having is when I try making WebStorm's File Watcher to do this step for me. When I configure the File Watcher as seen in the picture below:

[image: Setup File Watcher with Dart]

Then on change of my SCSS files the file watcher indeed triggers, but says:

> C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --no-cache --update viewQuestions.scss:viewQuestions.css
>   Unrecognized flags: cache, update
>
> Process finished with exit code 255

I tried removing the flags, but it lead to more errors, so I stopped trying. I then dropped the idea of doing it with Dart and re-configured it back with Ruby, with the same arguments, as seen in the picture below, which worked perfectly.

[image: Setup File Watcher with Ruby]

So my question would be what am I doing wrong, is it just Dart that needs different arguments or am I missing something more than that.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sass_builder works well for me for Dart projects. It is run as build step though.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Forgot to mention, I'm doing a Node project and I just wanted to locally compile my SCSS

Comment: 1) Run `where sass` to find out what program will run when you execute `sass` in terminal. Use that program in File Watcher. 2) If `dart.exe` is not found -- ensure that path to that program is listed in `PATH` system environment variable

Comment: @LazyOne That made it work. The where sass command showed me it's in _C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sass\tools_, so i've selected that in the FileWatcher. Added it in the Win10 _PATH_ var and one difference in the FileWatchers arguments was that it expected $FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css with no ":" between them, unlike Ruby. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As LazyOne suggested, I've found the solution to the problem by following the steps:

1) Running the "where sass" command, finding where the sass.bat is located

2) Passing that sass.bat in the *Program* field of WebStorm's File Watchers. It was here *C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sass\tools\sass.bat*

3) Then I followed https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml and added the Dart bin folder from *C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin* to Win10 *PATH* system environment variable

4) Finally, with a bit of tweaking found that in the File Watcher's Argument field the line should be $FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css with no ":" in between, unlike for Ruby

This worked for me in the end
[image: SCSS compiles successfully]

Comment: Sadly doesnt work anymore: `Error reading lstheme.scss: Cannot open file.`. Process finished with exit code 66.

Comment: This works as intended but I didnt use the sass.bat or the set the environment variable. The only thing I had to point at is the sass.exe

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to download a separate Dart SDK, as the Sass installer provides one.

It seems like you already followed the [installation instructions](https://sass-lang.com/install) and probably now have Sass for Windows installed in `c:\tools\dart-sass`, so you now have a file called `c:\tools\dart-sass\sass.bat`

This is what you should add to WebStorm in the `Tool to run on changes | Program` field (replacing the `c:\tools\ruby....bat` line).

Comment: I have found that sass.bat in _C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sass\tools_ , which I've set in the File Watcher settings. It now returns:

_cmd.exe /D /C call C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\sass.bat --no-cache --update viewQuestions.scss:viewQuestions.css
'dart.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Process finished with exit code 1_

I've also tried naively moving it in Dart's folder, but with no success

Comment: Try installing Sass again, using the `Install Anywhere (Standalone)` method. Download `dart-sass-1.3.2-windows-x64.zip` from the link provided. Unzip it and extract it to `c:\tools`. Check that it works by typing `c:\tools\dart-sass\sass.bat --version`. If that prints `1.3.2` proceed as above.

Comment: Also, where do you get the `--no-cache` and `--update` options? Neither seems to exist.

Comment: The --no-cache and --update were the default arguments when opening Webstorm's FileWatche for SCSSr. Buut Win10 _PATH_ var solved the problem, thank you for the hasty response nevertheless!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the correct answer: For those who are mac users and haven't already figure it out, this is what worked for me:

1. Install dart sass [instructions here](https://sass-lang.com/install) (NOTE: you might want to uninstall ruby sass first: `sudo gem uninstall ruby`)
2. Verify dart sass is working correctly: `sass path_to_file/your_sass_file.scss path_to_file/your_output_file.css`
3. In the Webstorm file watcher options set "Program" reference to: `usr/local/bin/sass` (this is where sass was installed by default for me)
4. For "Arguments" you can use: `$FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` (The `--update` argument also works but the `--cache argument` is not accepted by dart sass)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to correct answer, removing `--no-cache` in Argument field works for me.